# How to avoid local IPs from reaching remote PCs on enterprise LAN

Tags: windows, networking, lan

I am connected to LAN of my enterprise. For local IPs (192.168.x.x), I want that Windows only and only look for devices that are connected to specific ethernet adapter which is configured as 192.168.1.3 with a mask 255.255.255.0.

Let me show this:

```
Remote PC <----> LAN <----> (Ethernet#1 | PC | Ethernet#2) <----> Local Device
```

`Ethernet#1` is configured to get IP automatically to connect to enterprise LAN, which gets finally an IP in range `167.21.x.x` (And from this IP, it is able to reach to Remote PC!).

`Ethernet#2` is configured as `192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0`.

`Local Device` and `Remote PC` have IP `192.168.1.2`.

I do not want that my PC reach to Remote PC at all!

I want that `192.168.x.x` only goes through `Ethernet#2`.

How could I do that?

(*'Bypass proxy server for local addresses'* option does not work and not available for me)

Comment: Simple: configure Ethernet 1 to either not have an IP address at all, or to have IP address on a different subnet such as 192.168.0.0/24. That way remote PC 192.168.1.2 cannot reach that interface at all, and all traffic from local device 192.168.1.2 will be forwarded through Ethernet #2. However I am pretty sure this isn't exactly what you want to do... if not you need to clarify what exactly it is you want to achieve. Please do not answer in a comment, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679922/edit) your question instead to update it.

Comment: Ethernet#1 must get IP automatically to be able to connect to enterprise LAN, which gets an IP as 167.21.x.x.

Comment: It's not possible for remote PC 192.168.1.2 to reach Eth#1 167.21.x.x unless there's a router in between, possibly NAT as well. To prevent PC from reaching Remote PC you need a rule in the router closest to Remote PC that drops the traffic from PC to Remote PC; and vice versa. Or a firewall rule on either end of the data path. Local device 192.168.1.2 is only able to reach Eth#2 192.168.1.3, unless PC is routing between the networks. I'm sorry but your diagram is somewhat simplistic and information lacking to properly understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There is LAN! LAN has 3257352367 routers, gateways, whatever. Somehow through LAN I reach that remote PC. I do not believe that one needs network map of LAN to answer the question. It is unrelated. The question is if there is some thing to do on PC (windows) side or not. Can we tell or not "Hey Windows! If the IP that I want to reach begins with 192.168.x.x, NEVER use Ethernet#1! Only and only use Ethernet#2".

Comment: Something like `route add -p 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 0.0.0.0 IF <InterfaceNumber>` might work. InterfaceNumber you can find with command `route print`. Commands must be given in an elevated command prompt. Good luck.

Comment: Yes. With routing it first tries Ethernet#2. But it does not prevent it to try again Ethernet#1 as fallback.